# possible to run QuarkusTest without gradle plugin?

Tags: java, gradle, quarkus

We have multiple quarkus microservices, each as a gradle submodule. All of them were using the same old version gradle plugin `classpath "gradle.plugin.io.quarkus:quarkus-gradle-plugin:1.13.6.Final"` defined in the root `build.gradle`.

As I am upgrading one of the submodule `module-x` from 1.x to 3.x, I have to stop applying the old version of quarkus gradle plugin to `module-x` (I don't know how to specify gradle plugin version at submodule level, if you know the trick, let me know in your response). Then I found out that all `QuarkusTest` are skipped when I run `./gradlew :module-x:test`.

In summary, here are my questions

Is the [quarkus gradle plugin](https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/io.quarkus) a must-have in order to run `QuarkusTest`? any way to work around it?

Is that possible to apply different gradle plugin version at the submodule level?

Comment: Gradle is your build management tool that defines scopes and tasks. It also generates different entry points behind the scenes. You need to make quarkus and gradle talk to each other and sync their entry points and lifecycles - so there is no way around using the io.quarkus plugin with gradle. Even native images need to use maven/gradle beside calling main() as normal java execution. Thats not possible for tests or test suites.